# Crosstab in Cognos

Tags: cognos, crosstab

I have a set of data that needs to be displayed as a crosstab in Cognos. Example data includes

```
    ID, Month, Year, State
    1, 10, 2008, 25
    2, 10, 2008, 26
```

The problem is that in the crosstab, the month column is duplicated for each row instead of using the same column for the month.

Example:

```
ID   2008    2008
     10      10
1    25
2            26
```

Comment: Which version of Cognos are you using, and are you creating the report in Report Studio or Query Studio (assuming you are running 8.x)?

Comment: I am using Cognos 8.x. The report is created in Report Studio.

Comment: I'm still a little confused by the sample data.  Crosstab reports usually contain aggregates in the intersecting cells (but not always).  Is the 'State' column intended to be aggregated or is it an id/code?

Comment: The State column is an ID/Code

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Reworked the report after working on the view to keep the problem from occurring again.

Comment: This does not explain how the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Cognos guy but it sounds like your detail is not wrapped in an aggregate function like SUM(x).

Answer (score 0):

Cognos allows you to enter SQL Queries in addition of plain reporting of data. Try to dive into that

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what you drug out into your cross tab by the row, column and measure drop zones?  Is your data source relational data or a cube?  With a little more info, I think we can figure this out.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Report, basic purpose is to show the Aggregations based on some criteria. but in your example, the data provided does not make any sense that WHAT actually you want in Cross Table?...if you can define what you want then solution is really simple...